# Does StandardTokenizer remove punctuation (in Lucene 4.1)

Tags: java, lucene

Does StandardTokenizer remove punctuation (in Lucene 4.1)

Im just trying to move back to StandardTokenizer from my own old custom implemenation because the newer version seems to have much better support for Asian languages

However this code except fails on incrementToken() implying that the !!! are removed from output, yet looking at the jflex classes I cant see anything to indicate punctuation is removed, is it removed and if so can i prevent its removal ?

```
Tokenizer tokenizer = new StandardTokenizer(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_VERSION, new StringReader("!!!"));
assertNotNull(tokenizer);
tokenizer.reset();
assertTrue(tokenizer.incrementToken());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, punctuation will be removed (speaking very generally, it's more complex that just that).  The string you've provided effectively has zero tokens after going through the tokenizer.  `StandardTokenizer` implements [UAX #29](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/), so you can read that over for a complete description.

It does this to separate the input into tokens representing, roughly, words.  Since you want punctuation to remain a part of your tokens in one way or another, I'm guessing that indexing words isn't really what you want to do, so `StandardTokenizer` is probably just not a good choice.

Comment: Thx, I do want to index words but my definition of words is basically whitespace only because Im dealing with music artist names where punctuation is often used as part of the name. Any ideas ?

Comment: Sure, [WhitespaceTokenizer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/WhitespaceTokenizer.html).

Comment: Ah yes just looking at this, I think a custom tokenizer based on pure java code rather than one based on jflex is the way to go, my difficulty is that it is meant to support ALL languages plus non-words as well !

Comment: @PaulTaylor In that case you'll probably want to choose your tokenizer based on the language. Solr has a page about what it uses for language detection https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageDetection